# iOS: lock screen orientation change for time

Tags: ios, uikit

How to lock screen orientation change for, let's say, 5 seconds from the app launch?

I need the following behaviour:

1. App launches in actual orientation (taken from info.plist file and device orientation)
2. Orientation freezes for some time (e.g. 5 sec), app doesn't respond to device rotations
3. After this time app updates it's orientation to actual device state — can be skipped if device was not rotated